# Nav Pills Background Leak

Tags: css, navigation

I am looking to use navigation pills on my website, but they are resulting in a background leak. See the effect on this website: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/tutorial-how-to-sort-and-group-uitableview-by-date/. Hover over the pills multiple times to see the issue. You can see the outline of the pills appear.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
    .navigation-main {
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        padding-top: 5px;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        font: 700 13px/1.3076923076 Lato, sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: .05em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navigation-main .menu {
        max-width: 1272px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .navigation-main ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navigation-main li {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .navigation-main li:after {
        content: none;
        display: block;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin-top: -4px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .navigation-main li:last-child:after {
        content: none;
    }

    .navigation-main a {
        display: block;
        line-height: 2.6153846153;
        padding: 0 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .navigation-main ul ul {
        background-color: #000;
        display: none;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2.6153846153em;
        left: 0;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 99999;
    }

    .navigation-main li li {
        display: block;
    }

    .navigation-main li li:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navigation-main ul ul ul {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }

    .navigation-main ul ul a {
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 1.3076923076;
        padding: .6153846153em 10px .6923076923em;
        white-space: normal;
        width: 170px;
    }

    .navigation-main ul ul a:hover {
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navigation-main ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

/* This is where the pill happens */
    .navigation-main a:hover,
    .navigation-main li.current_page_item > a,
    .navigation-main li.current-menu-item > a {
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #000;
    }
```

How do I stop the outline from appearing? Thanks!

**Edit:**
Code tried:

```
.navigation-main li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 100px;


.navigation-main a:hover,
.navigation-main li.current_page_item > a,
.navigation-main li.current-menu-item > a {
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem in Firefox 23. Hovered over the top navigation section multiple times and nothing odd happened.

Comment: Safari is the browser I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your css:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

Add it to any item using border-radius.

Here is exactly what you need to write change for your example. Tried and verified.

```
body > header nav li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #0a6abf;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

**with background-clip**

[image: 1]

**without background-clip**

[image: 1]

Comment: Try again, I just verified that it does in fact fix it in Safari.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help. I'll try it again and verify the css.

Comment: I tried it, but its still not working. My live site: shaansingh.me. My code is in edit.

Comment: Triple check that your cache is cleared, because I'm not able to make it happen on your like site. It looks good.

Comment: Works in chrome but not safari. Should I use -webkit?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Safari 6.0.5 in Mountain Lion.

Comment: Im using the same thing, perhaps your on a Retina Macbook Pro? I could see an issue with it doubling the pixels, and possibly causing that effect. Otherwise its just not happening. Sorry no one else is chiming in, to confirm or deny.

Comment: I'm on a regular Macbook Pro (non-retina). I cleared the caches from the Develop menu, but I'm not sure why this is happening. FYI, the site looks normal on my iPad and on Google Chrome.

Comment: The amount of background leaking is less for sure, but not actually gone.